# How to convert bit number to digit

Tags: vba, excel

I'm working to create an Excel macro using VBA to convert bit strings to numbers. They are not binary numbers, each '1' stands for it's own number.

e.g: 1100000000000000000010001

from the left, the first bit represents "1", the second bit represents "2", third bit represents "0", and so on. The total quantity of bits in each string is 25.

I want VBA to convert it and show results like so: 1, 2, 21, 25.

I tried using Text to Columns but was not successful.

Comment: You can use `Mid()` to access each digit and convcert it to it's relevant number (you can store those in an array or even a worksheet range). However, if you don't know *any* VBA this is not really the place to learn...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another non-VBA solution, based on the OP' initial approach and with a layout designed to facilitate multiple 'conversions' (ie copy formulae down to suit):

[image]

Comment: there is a typo in cell BZ. should be "=LEFT(BY1,LEN(BY1)-1)" . thanks for helping!

Comment: Any idea on how to remove the "0"?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Sub Execute()
    Dim buff() As String
    Dim i As Integer, total As Double

    buff = Split(StrConv(<theString>, vbUnicode), Chr$(0))
    total = 0

    For i = 0 To UBound(buff)
        Debug.Print (buff(i))
        'total = total + buff(i) * ??
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: hi @Makah, I'm using Excel 2010. I copied this VBA and paste into Excel module, upon compiling in VBA, an error appeared. The 4th line appeared red.

Comment: Hey @user2755335, you need to change <theString> for your real string "0001010101001011010" :-)

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

```
Public Function BitPicker(sIn As String) As String
    For i = 1 To Len(sIn)
        If Mid(sIn, i, 1) = 1 Then
            BitPicker = BitPicker & i & ","
        End If
    Next
        BitPicker = Mid(BitPicker, 1, Len(BitPicker) - 1)
End Function
```

Comment: Hi pnuts:  I envisioned the data to be a cell, like A1.  =BitPicker(A1) would be entered in another cell and that cell would display the results (comma-separated)  Thanks for the vote!

Answer (score 0):

Does this have to be VBA?  Give a data setup like this:

[image: Convert from bit string]

The formula in cell B4 and copied down to B33 is:

```
=IF(ROWS(B$3:B3)>LEN($B$1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE($B$1,"1","")),"",FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE($B$1,"1","@",ROWS(B$3:B3))))
```

The formula cells are formatted as General and the the Bit String cell (B1) is formatted as Text.

Comment: thanks @tigeravatar , this is much simpler. but I can't barely understand the command. if I want the result to be shown horizontally i.e: C1,C2, and so on, which parameter should be change?

Comment: Change both instances of `ROWS(B$3:B3)` to instead be `COLUMNS(B$3:B3)` and then you can copy right instead of down

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  Function ConvertMyRange(Rng As Range) As String

  Dim MyString As String
  MyString = Rng.Text
  Dim OutPutString As String

     For i = 1 To Len(MyString)
        If Mid(MyString, i, 1) = "1" Then OutPutString = OutPutString & ", " & i
     Next i

     ' Get rid of first ", " that was added in the loop
     If Len(OutPutString) > 0 Then
        OutPutString = Mid(OutPutString, 2)
     End If

     ConvertMyRange = OutPutString

  End Function
```

For your input, the output is 1, 2, 21, 25